# Infimum of $A:= \{x\in \mathbb{Q}:-1< x< \sqrt{2} \text{ or } x^2= 2\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

The answer was given $-\sqrt{2}$, but $A$ contains only rationals, so $\sqrt{2}\notin A$ and $-\sqrt{2}\notin A$ as well.  Thus the set $A$ shrinks to the set of all rational numbers, between $-1$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

My answer, when I solved the problem, was $\inf A= -1$. The proof goes like

Since $-1< x\,\,\forall x\in A$, therefore $-1$ is an lower bound of $A$. Let's choose any arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\varepsilon>0$, we have from the Archimedean property that $\exists \,p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{p}< \varepsilon\Rightarrow -1+\dfrac{1}{p}<-1+\varepsilon$.

Since $\dfrac{1}{p}\in \mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow -1+\dfrac{1}{p}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $-1+\dfrac{1}{p} > -1$, thus $-1+\dfrac{1}{p}\in A$ and $-1< -1+\dfrac{1}{p}< -1+\varepsilon\Rightarrow \inf A= -1$

Comment: Your answer is correct (only that $-1$ is a *lower* bound).

Comment: The answer given is for infimum of $A:= \{x\in \mathbb{Q}:-1< x< \sqrt{2}\}\cup \{x \in \mathbb R: x^2= 2\}$

Comment: Suppose $-\sqrt{2}\in A$, but still it can't be greatest lower bound, since there exist no $x\in A$ in between $-\sqrt{2}$ and $-1$, right? So the answer that inf $A=-\sqrt{2}$ is totally wrong, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for $x^2 = 2$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, so the set in question is $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : -1 < x < \sqrt{2}\}$. Clearly, the infimum is $-1$ since $-1$ is a lower bound and if we had some lower bound $M > -1$, we would have some rational $x$ such that $-1 < x < M$ by the density of the rationals.

In other words, your answer is correct.